# adding a background image turns the background all black - likely image not detected

Tags: ios, ios5

I created a group called img and put an image there that I wanted to appear as the background.

But instead, the background turned all black.

Here is the code I used for this.  I put the code in the `viewDidAppear` method

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img/building.png"]];
```

any thought on what I might have done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `[self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"building.png"]];` instead

Comment: Sposibo :) ....but it still didn't work. What is the difference in your approach?

Comment: I thought that the problem was in the name `@"img/building.png"`. Are U using bundle or the image is just in project?

Comment: just saw you are from Odessa - Chernomorets vpered!!! :)  ..ja tozhe ot tuda :)   ...about the image, I am probably going wrong in adding the image incorrectly. What is the right way to do that? I dragged the image into the root directory first, and after the ls command, I do not see the image there, but if I do a git status command, it shows the image.

Comment: Delete the image from the project, then drag the image into xcode project navigator (tree of files) and when appears a window, check "Copy items into destination group's folder (if needed)". That's all. Then use the code I wrote. I have just tried it on my mac and it worked

Comment: Thanks for this! We just ran into this problem and realized the image was not selected for the correct Target Membership in the File Inspector.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are loading an image from the application bundle? If this is the case, the UIImage is not being created correctly.

Try:

```
UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"building" ofType:@"png"]];
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:image];
```

Comment: I just dragged the image into that directory. Was that a bad practice approach by me? What is the correct way to do this generally? Thanks!

Comment: When I click on the img directory in xCode, I do not see the image there.  But if I do an ls command in the shell, the image does appear there.

Comment: The directory doesn't matter if XCode properly added the image to the application bundle. When you dragged and dropped, did it ask you whether you would like to add the image to the app bundle?

Comment: Just because the image is in the same directory as the rest of the appliction, does not mean it is in the application bundle

Comment: 1. move the image to the desired location and then 2. Click and drag the image over XCode or the XCode icon

Comment: no it didn't ask that when I dragged and dropped.  Furthermore, now that I double-check, the img directory does not appear after the ls command...but I do see an empty img directory in xCode ...confusing :)

Comment: A terminal shell is unnecessary. 1. Move the image into the directory that is named after the app (should be located right next to the App.XCodeProject file. 2. Once the file is in there, click that file from finder and drag it over to the XCode icon

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15012/discussion-between-geekedout-and-eli-gregory)